# Enable bootstrap responsive only on mobile device

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have been searching around and have found no answer or solution for this problem:

I would like to enable bootstrap responsive only when users are using mobile devices. In other words when users are using computer browsers, responsive will be turned off, meaning no matter how the user resize the window, there is always a minimum width for my container and responsiveness will never kick in.

Is there any way to do this by default?

Comment: Yes, You can do it with help of javascript (jquery) mobile detection. But if you want some help, you must include HTML and CSS so far you've completed.

Answer (score 1):

with bootstrap 3: just add a new class to yours containers, like cFixed, and only in the 'min-width: 768px' media-query set your container dimension et voila

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .cFixed{width:1174px}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We need to add an extra responsive stylesheet  css/bootstrap-responsive.css

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css">
```

And following are the supported devices

```
/* Large desktop */
@media (min-width: 1200px) { ... }

/* Portrait tablet to landscape and desktop */
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) { ... }

/* Landscape phone to portrait tablet */
@media (max-width: 767px) { ... }

/* Landscape phones and down */
@media (max-width: 480px) { ... }
```

Responsive utility classes

[image]

Comment: He already mentioned this - "In other words when users are using computer browsers, responsive will be turned off, meaning no matter how the user resize the window"... This answer of yours still works responsive on browser resize!

Comment: Yes, I just gave the information about responsive utility classes thinking might be helpful.

Answer (score -1):

You can separate your responsive and non-responsive styling by device width in CSS.

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    /* Responsive styling */
    div {
        width: 50%;
    }
    ...
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    /* Non-responsive styling */
    div {
        width: 500px;
    }
    ...
}
```

Note, this does not determine if the device is mobile or not. To do that, you could make use of open source JavaScript (i.e. http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/).

Comment: He already mentioned this - "In other words when users are using computer browsers, responsive will be turned off, meaning no matter how the user resize the window"

Comment: Right so when width >= 768, you style elements with fixed width and when < 768, you style using responsiveness.  This is also why I added the note about mobile detection.